# How to remove 6 month before logs using python script

Tags: python, linux, unix, logging

I have `Logs_26052021.tar.xz`
Description: `26052021--> date: 26, month: 05, year: 2021`

And want to permanently remove this kind of files from location using python script.
its on Unix server, version: `Linux localhost 3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64`

what should I do.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Answer,

```
find /path/Logs/ -name "*.log.*" -type f -mtime +180
```

But while executing this command getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  for `"*.log.*"`

How should I execute this one using python ?

Answer (score 0):

using proper separation into methods. Tested on python 3.9.6

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime


def get_files_from_path(path: str) -> list:
    result = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + filename
            if filename.startswith('Logs_') and filename.endswith('.tar.xz'):
                result.append(filepath)
    return result    


def get_old_files(filelist: list, max_days=184) -> list:
    currentdate = datetime.now()
    result = []
    for file in filelist:
        datestr = file.split('Logs_')[1].split('.tar.xz')[0]
        filedate = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d%m%Y')
        tdelta = currentdate - filedate
        if tdelta.days > max_days:
            result.append(file)
    return result


def delete_files(filelist: list):
    for file in filelist:
        os.remove(file)


logfiles = get_files_from_path('testing')
oldfiles = get_old_files(logfiles)

delete_files(oldfiles)
```

related documentation:

1. [Iterate over files](https://newbedev.com/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory#3-using-code-os-walk-code-)
2. [strptime behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
3. [timedelta for substraction of dates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)
4. [File deletion](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_remove.asp)

Comment: This is traditional python way, looking for unix command which we can execute with python to remove 6 month old files

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you here. You ask for a python script, and then you say here that you want a *nix command. Which do you want? Update your question and tags accordingly...